# Block all traffic except some from Microsoft servers and some to selected sites, with iptables

Tags: linux, router, firewall, iptables, dd-wrt

I have a D-Link router model DIR-600 with DD-WRT firmware.

I need to configure `iptables` so I can block all traffic, except from Microsoft servers (i.e. Microsoft updates must work), and except HTTP traffic to some selected sites.

Is it easy to do? I think someone who has Linux knowledge can do that within a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

This is not easy to do [properly] because it [requires a knowledge of Microsoft Update Server IP addresses, which are not fully public knowledge](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_other-update/windows-update-servers-ip-address-range/7d86bbb7-ce5e-468a-b662-c2db574d1526), change from time-to-time, and will differ depending on where you are.

IPTables also runs at the IP address rather then domain name level, so tying it in to DNS, while arguably not impossible, is not very practical.

(I qualify as someone who has Linux knowledge - I maintain Linux servers - including Linux based routers - for a living, and I certainly can't do this in a few minutes)

Comment: Okay, thank you for your answer. I understand it. Hmmm.. Okay, so the router can't be like a firewall? It's not safe?

Comment: A router can most definitely be a firewall - and iptables is firewalling software.  The issue is more "what you are trying to do".  That said, you might want to try advise what you are trying to do (It may be a language barrier, but your post is not clear - ie where does http protocol come into it and what does "so as to all trafic must be block without microsoft" actually mean ? ( I took it to mean that the only servers which can be accessed belong to Microsoft )

Comment: My friend has a small business and he wants to allow his employees to use some sites that he sets. A few computers will be connected to the Internet and these computers should get updates from microsoft. Other traffic is not desirable.You know for example I want to give an access to "wikipedia or gmail" websites only for my employees and nothing more. A simple sheme: Computers can get updates from microsoft windows update and can connected to websites which will be set by me.

Comment: I would think that employing a proxy such as squid or something similar would be more effective and efficient. That would seem like the most logical choice.